# Print high-quality documents using system rather than embedded fonts?

Tags: fonts, compiling

This question may be easy, but I am stuck with some PDF pages trying to include them in my document. The normal way for `pdflatex` is just to insert the lines:

```
\usepackage{pdfpages} % in the preamble 
.
.
.
\includepdf[pages={<range>}]{filename.pdf} % in body
```

For pure `latex.exe`, I was unable to find a corresponding method. For some good reason, I use the sequence `LaTeX->DVI->PS->PDF` to generate my PDF. There are a number of posts also giving the same advice like [this](http://slantchev.ucsd.edu/edu/latex/latex-pdf.html) post and [this](http://dsanta.users.ch/resources/type1.html).

I have tried to insert separate pages as `.eps` images, but this created many problems as each image has a full page size, besides being very tedious to convert a big range of PDF pages. Thank you for your advice.

My current code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{helvet}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[subscriptcorrection,zswash,straightbraces]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage{graphicx,rotating,setspace}
\usepackage{tikz}   
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor,multirow}
\usepackage[top=25mm,bottom=25mm,right=25mm,left=35mm]{geometry}    
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}

The whole document goes here ...

\end{document}
```

**UPDATE:** As per @UlrikeFischer request:

You can find a complete example with output `.PDF`, `.tex` and `.log` files [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6iNjbZ7CUFPYkRjT0ZVTHEtbm8/view?usp=sharing). Kindly test the attachments.

Comment: It’s likely to be impossible to include PDF files in your document if you’re producing PostScript first.  As you’ve found out, converting to EPS first would work, but apparently it’s inconvenient for you.  What exactly is the reason why you have to produce DVI first?

Comment: I am submitting an important work which is required to be typeset with high quality and the fonts should be embedded. That's why I choose the `LaTeX->DVI->PS->PDF` sequence. I tried `pdflatex` but the quality is not acceptable.

Comment: @AboAmmar Direct PDF output should give just as good quality as the 'traditional' route, but the reasons you've got an issue are a different question.

Comment: It sounds like you’re having a bitmap font problem.  This can usually be solved.  I suggest you ask a question about that, describing what font you’re using exactly, rather than trying to work around the problem.

Comment: @JosephWright The direct PDF output is good on screen only. On paper, the letters are distorted if you make a close look, especially, the letters: o, a, fi, d ... but when I use the traditional method I can use True Type fonts of high quality.

Comment: @AboAmmar Again, that’s a problem that can be solved, but of course we need specifics.  And I really doubt it’s TrueType fonts you’re using with the DVI route.

Comment: @ArthurReutenauer  I don't mean literally True Type fonts but at least standard postscript ones of high quality. I added details.

Comment: @AboAmmar Thanks, that helps a bit.  Is the the double-stroked letters of bbm you’re having a problem with?  All the other font packages you’re using can be easily used with pdfTeX, or replaced with something equivalent.

Comment: @ArthurReutenauer The problem is not related to math fonts I think; they are great (thanks to the powerful `mtpro2`). The text, however, looks poor on paper. PDF properties tell that the font is `Nimbus Roman No9 L` of course.

Comment: @AboAmmar Why “of course”?  Anyway, that’s just a Times clone; try the TeX Gyre version instead, Termes (`\usepackage{tgtermes}`).

Comment: I used this too. I tried nearly all options i'm aware of, but I can't get a text quality as good as, e.g. MS Word using `Times New Roman`  at the same `fontsize` and other settings. The latter prints on paper very crisp.

Comment: Well, if you’ve got Times New Roman as a True Type font you can use that one too.  With pdfTeX.

Comment: @ArthurReutenauer  As I said, I tried every possible option I'm aware of, even this one. The only way I get super-high quality output is the traditional sequence `LaTeX->DVI->PS->PDF`, but including figures and PDF pages is a real pain in that case.

Comment: Did you?  By generating a TFM and a map file entry?  Anyway, if you insist on not using pdfTeX and still want an easy way to include PDF documents I really don’t think I can help you.

Comment: @ArthurReutenauer  I accept using any engine which can give me the acceptable quality, so how can I achieve this? All methods that I know didn't help! Unfortunately, I can't show you the printed output to compare or even upload the PDF file.

Comment: BTW, I heard about an old package `timesnew.sty` which contains only three lines of code, but I don't find any documentation describing the correct configuration for it. It's supposed to make available `Times New Roman` for use with `pdflatex`.

Comment: Imho there can be a difference between pdflatex  and latex+dvips only if the one route doesn't embed the fonts. Check the font properties of the resulting pdfs.

Comment: @AboAmmar You can scan an extract at high resolution.  And you don’t need a package to use any TrueType font with pdfTeX, you just need to generate a TFM file and use an appropriate map file statement.  See section 5.2 of the pdfTeX users manual for basic instructions, and there probably are tutorials in many places, including this site.

Comment: I don't think that the following is related to a solution, but
pdflatex supports TrueType fonts to some extents:
`% pdflatex (assume standard windows fonts)`
`\documentclass[12pt]{article}`
`\usepackage{times}`
`\pdfmapline{ptmr8r <8r.enc <times.ttf}`
`\pdfmapline{ptmri8r <8r.enc <timesi.ttf}`
`\pdfmapline{ptmb8r <8r.enc <timesbd.ttf}`
`\pdfmapline{ptmbi8r <8r.enc <timesbi.ttf}`
`\begin{document}`
`This is a test. \textbf{test} \textit{test\bfseries\ test}.`
`\end{document}`

Comment: FYI, in the TeX Live 2015, pdfpages package can be used
in latex as follows. Note that lastpage=<lastpage>
is necessary:
`% latex + dvipdfmx`
`\documentclass{article}`
`\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}`
`\usepackage[dvips]{pdfpages}`
`\begin{document}`
`\includepdf[pages={1,3,5},lastpage=9]{testpdf.pdf}`
`\end{document}`

Comment: @AkiraKakuto  Your code embedded the font indeed, but some `ligatures` as `fi` appear as empty square in `italic` mode. Also, it is so strange that the quality is still not equal to the `latex+dvips` approach (but slightly better than direct pdflatex). @UlrikeFischer, I wonder why it is still not as good as `latex+dvips` even if the fonts are now embedded as you mentioned.

Comment: You haven't show any proof that there is a difference. Upload two example pdfs somewhere along with the .tex-file and the log-files. Then someone can perhaps tell you what's going on.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  Ok, I uploaded the files under this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6iNjbZ7CUFPYkRjT0ZVTHEtbm8/view?usp=sharing   Please test the two folders and observe the difference. (The difference is more clear on paper).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I already wrote in a comment: the most probable source for a difference between the pdflatex and the latex+dvips route is not embedded fonts.

Your pdfs show exactly this difference. pdflatex embeds fonts for the text (nimbus in this case, "eingebettet" means embedded):

[image]

But dvips doesn't, so the fonts provided by "the system" are used:

[image]

On my system and with my printer I can't see a difference between both, but it is naturally possible that something in your printing chain handles a pdf without embedded font better.

You can avoid embedding the fonts with pdflatex by setting the suitable option in updmap.cfg in miktex:

Run on the command line:

```
initexmf --edit-config-file updmap
```

An editor will open your local updmap.cfg. Enter:

```
pdftexDownloadBase14 false
```

Save the file. Then run on the command line:

```
updmap
```

to update your map-files.

But before doing this, read the remark regarding this option in the main `updmap.cfg`:

```
#
# pdftexDownloadBase14
#
# Should pdftex download the base 14 pdf fonts? Since some configurations
# (ps / pdf tools / printers) use bad default fonts, it is safer to download
# the fonts. The pdf files will get bigger, though.
# Valid settings are true (download the fonts) or false (don't download
# the fonts).
pdftexDownloadBase14 true
```

Comment: Wow, well done!  We got there in the end :-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks a ton, Madam. You're awesome! One last inquiry, though, are you sure you didn't see any defects using your printer? in that case I can print elsewhere. For all other people here, thank you for your time. Can you please examine printing on paper? Your feedback is highly appreciated.

Comment: @AboAmmar If Ulrike’s answer addressed your problem, could you please edit your question to reflect the actual question that she answered?  It really doesn’t have anything to do with pdfpages any more, and this discussion may be useful to other people in the future.

Comment: @ArthurReutenauer I agree. Thanks. BTW, did you examine printing my PDF files?

Comment: @AboAmmar No, as it seemed Ulrike had addressed your problem, but I can print them at work tomorrow.